# Error configuring nginx to point to the Jenkins server

Tags: nginx, jenkins

I have got Jenkins running on a CentOS 7 VM with IP say `129.215.193.34`. So, I can access Jenkins using `129.215.193.34:8080`. I wanted to uses `nginx` so users don't have to type `:8080` and just the IP number. 
After installing nginx and inserting the following in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

But I am getting a generic error when accessing to `129.215.193.34`. How can I know what is wrong here? I can see Jenkins web interface on `129.215.193.34:8080` but nothing on just `129.215.193.34`

The rest of the `nginx.conf` looks like this

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
        location / {
           sendfile off;
           proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
           proxy_redirect     default;

           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the server section? can you put the entire nginx conf here?

Comment: @Rik Sure, sorry. let me update it.

Comment: Try changing the `server` part listening only to outside ip. `listen 129.215.193.34:80 deafult_server` and restart nginx. In location there is a duplicate `proxy_redirect` but all you need to make it work is the `proxy_pass`. SO you might want to try that first.

Comment: Actually I think that the `proxy_redirect   off;` blows it for you. Just use the first 3 lines in `location / {...}` and check that

Comment: @Rik I have tried with just those three lines in the `location` section but it does not work. Also replaced the `listen` sections with `listen 129.215.193.34:80 deafult_server` but I get an error restarting `Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.`

Comment: You can try `0.0.0.0:80`. And what does `nginx -t` say?

Comment: @Rik with `0.0.0.0:80` `nginx -t ` says everything is OK, however if I don't type `:8080` on the web browser I can't reach the `Jenkins` web interface

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135602/discussion-between-rik-and-manolete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify if the nginx configuration is correct by running (as root)

```
nginx -t
```

If that is correct, check that the proxy works (you should find something in nginx configuration). Run

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

and curl to the machine

```
curl -I http://<ip>:80/
```

On SELinux, [allow daemons to connect to the service](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans#line-44)

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

on the host.